# Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i use ubuntu 16.04 and kinetic kame, when i try to build a package, it returns:

usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"

someone knows something about it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233786/parse-error-at-%22boost_join%22/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on 2016-06-01**:
I have the same problem. According to [this thread at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455178/qt4-cgal-parse-error-at-boost-join) it might be because of mismatching Boost and QT versions.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2016-06-27**:
I have the same problem as well :-(

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2016-10-05**:
Hello, Did you fix it?

**Comment by [zhaoyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25681/zhaoyang/) on 2016-10-11**:
i have the same problem when i try rgbdslam-v2.;-(
ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just fixed adding as "The Martin" said:

In qnode.cpp:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "../include/testpackage/qnode.hpp"
#include <ros/network.h>
#endif
```

---

Originally posted by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) with karma: 330 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on 2017-01-19**:
Did you add a separate qnode.cpp file, or the file was exisiting, and you edited it??

**Comment by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) on 2017-07-18**:
As an addition: The `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN .. #endif` statement has to encapsulate all ros- and boost-related includes in your code. It should not encapsulate Qt or STL-includes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://blog.csdn.net/h321654/article/details/54582341
The steps:

1. sudo gedit /usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp
2. Modify "namespace BOOST_JOIN(BOOST_TT_TRAIT_NAME,_impl) {...}" to
   "
   #ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
   namespace BOOST_JOIN(BOOST_TT_TRAIT_NAME,_impl) {
   #endif
   ....
   #ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
   }
   #endif
   "

---

Originally posted by [lhz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32519/lhz/) with karma: 31 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) on 2018-07-04**:
On my Ubuntu 16.04 with Kinetic, it worked like a charm, thank you! Here is [a patch](https://pastebin.com/5QMFMMs0) for anybody stumbling in this issue.

**Comment by [Pedro Machado](https://answers.ros.org/users/50779/pedro-machado/) on 2020-01-08**:
worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04